# PHP MySQL select where $id is in string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

how could I select the values from the table where my passed ID value is inside a string? Values of columns can be `3326,9023,3725,552,1559` or `3326`, it's a string of n values. I need to get the row if my passed ID is inside this string.

Query:

```
$result = $this->db->query("
        SELECT b.*
        FROM `values` AS `b`
        WHERE b.ids = ?
    ", array($id))->row_array();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list of ids is in the column values, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to search for your passed id:

```
$result = $this->db->query("
        SELECT b.*
        FROM `values` AS `b`
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, b.ids)
    ", array($id))->row_array();
```

Answer (score 2):

use `in` if you want use list of ids

```
SELECT b.*
        FROM `values` AS `b`
        WHERE b.ids in (3326,9023,3725,552,1559,3326) // your list of ids
```

but if value is string then use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(table.id, commaSeparatedstringvalue);
```

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think they have an `ids` field in the database which could look something like `'3326,9023,3725,552,1559'` and they want to find a row which, for example, matches `'9023'`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca let me check again btw thanks for information